# How to examine mono framework when debugging an Android app in VS2019

Tags: debugging, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging an Android app built with Xamarin Forms. I am stopped at a breakpoint in VS2019 debugger.

As you can see in the screenshot, **the debugger already knows the file names and line numbers**. I did not do any symbol setup to make this happen (just created a new Xamarin Forms app and VS2019 already had this line number information).

[image]

Is it possible to debug the mono code? Ideally, I'd like to step through either the real source code, or disassembled code. But even if I could just double-click on a stack frame and examine the variables that would already be helpful.

Comment: You could check the blog below. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/debugging-xamarin-mono/ And the Extension Sample would be helpful. https://github.com/xamarin/vs-mono-debugger-sample